# Is HealthKit query on WatchOS limited?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

The same code for fetching HKCorrelation (Blood Pressure) on iPhone returns all records, but on watch just 4. Is there a documentation explaining such behavior?

It looks like only records added after installing the app on watch are synced.

Comment: Yes many articles and you can find it on apple document also, https://medium.com/@gorillalogic/apple-watch-healthkit-developer-tutorial-how-to-build-a-workout-app-de156733dd6a

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a clue nor documentation. It only says "Apple Watch have their own data, and iOS is the one in charge of synchronizing that data." without any details.

Comment: API also given by apple : https://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Welcome/573402/608431-4.html

Comment: Lynda is not free, so I cannot check that link and link to Apple documentation is not answering my question. That's just quantity type doc.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcorrelationtypeidentifier/1615325-bloodpressure

Comment: What you want same app i found on app store also so it's possible. You must have to read all documentation properly. I also read and update you.

Comment: Still, I couldn’t find any specific info nowhere. Also similar apps shows last 3 records, or present some data from HK statistics query. Do I can just guess how it works, but I was wondering if that’s explicitly documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that on iPhone HKHealthStore returns all records, however on watch only records added by release versions of the app are fetched. That's why I didn't see the same data on watch as on iPhone.