# HealthKit on watchos is only returning results for the last week

Tags: healthkit, watchos

Is there a way to get a HealthKit query run on watchos to return the full set of results in a way that is not limited by time?  The same code which I have running on ios and which returns all results, when run on watchos, drops any results that are older than a week.  Results that were showing from 6 days ago from a particular day are not included in query results the next day when run on the watch.

This question:

1] [Is HealthKit query on WatchOS limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925000/is-healthkit-query-on-watchos-limited)

was answered with a suggestion that a query performed with a release build would return all results, but this doesn't seem to be correct and also is not consistent with the week-long limit that I've observed.

If this is simply a limit that is inherent with WatchOS, where is it documented?

If there is a way to overcome the limit, please specify how.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch does not have all health data on device. It only contains a weeks worth of data so the results you are getting are expected. The full data is available on the paired iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Can you point to the place where this limitation is documented?